# SQL Server management studio debugger error

Tags: sql-server, debugging, ssms

SQL server debugger has been down from two days ago suddenly and without any new installation or remove any software from my PC.

I searched a lot but didn't find anything

[image: this is first image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of searching and finding no answer
To solve my problem, I installed "Devart dbForgere studio" software to continue my work 
And surprisingly, my problem was solved in SSMS